# CSS: border-color:inherit

Tags: html, css

I have a button with border on the right and the bottom, when I hover that, both border is hidden, and show border on the top and the left with color same as background-color on parent that button, i want to make like a 3D button effect, but its not working.

Here's look like my button when i hover it

[image]

What i want is the border-color is red, and if the parent background-color is green the border-color is green

And here's my code

```
.cta {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-family: 'courier new' !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    background: #1d85bf;
    color:#fff;
    border:3px solid #0b527a;
    border-top:0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cta:hover {
    border:3px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-color:inherit !important;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px !important;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/evpsthx3/

Comment: "same color". Have you tried simply using `transparent` or alpha? Could you create a mockup of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: please also share html part, or fiddle would be great

Comment: please share your html code?

Comment: See my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/evpsthx3/

Comment: When you set `inherit` value you get the value of the parent for that property, you haven't `border-color` in the parent of `.cta` button

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp it say border-color hasn't inherit value :/

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi 
No. What it says is not directly inherited from his parent the value (like the color of the font do), when you use the value `inherit` you force to do it. Sorry my English, I hope you understand me

Comment: **Inherited:** no. But the possible values are: `border-color: color  | transparent | initial | inherit;`

Comment: Is inherited and inherit is different thing?

Comment: Yes. For example `color` property is inherited, if you set the color in the `body` tag all text get that color if you don't set another. `border` is not inherited, if you put a border to the `body` its descendant don't have a border too. But you can do any property inherited with the `inherit` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your parent has no border color set. So just set the border color to the parent. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/evpsthx3/9/

```
<div class="parent red">
<a class="cta">BUTTON</a>
</div>

<div class="parent green">
<a class="cta">BUTTON</a>
</div>



.parent.red {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

.parent.green {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give that effect by adding the below css code, Hope it wrks.

---

```
.cta:hover {box-shadow: #000 5px 5px 5px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
.parent {
  width:300px;
  height:60px;
  padding:30px;
}

.cta {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-family: 'courier new' !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    background: #1d85bf;
    color:#fff;
    border:3px solid #0b527a;
    border-top:0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.cta:hover {
    border:3px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-color:inherit !important;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px !important;
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: #242729 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/evpsthx3/7/)